# Why MySQL needs to add num 2 when calculating the scan_time for the table scan function?

Tags: mysql

When calculating the scan_time for the table scan ,why MySQL needs to add num 2 in the following line? What is the reason or purpose of adding 2? [code url](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc#L16536)

return(ulonglong2double(stats.data_file_length) / IO_SIZE + *2*);

```
ha_innobase::scan_time()
/*====================*/
{
    /* Since MySQL seems to favor table scans too much over index
    searches, we pretend that a sequential read takes the same time
    as a random disk read, that is, we do not divide the following
    by 10, which would be physically realistic. */

    /* The locking below is disabled for performance reasons. Without
    it we could end up returning uninitialized value to the caller,
    which in the worst case could make some query plan go bogus or
    issue a Valgrind warning. */

    if (m_prebuilt == NULL) {
        /* In case of derived table, Optimizer will try to fetch stat
        for table even before table is create or open. In such
        cases return default value of 1.
        TODO: This will be further improved to return some approximate
        estimate but that would also needs pre-population of stats
        structure. As of now approach is in sync with MyISAM. */
        return(ulonglong2double(stats.data_file_length) / IO_SIZE + 2);
    }

    ulint   stat_clustered_index_size;

    ut_a(m_prebuilt->table->stat_initialized);

    stat_clustered_index_size =
        m_prebuilt->table->stat_clustered_index_size;

    return((double) stat_clustered_index_size);
}
```

Comment: When you seem not to want the tag [meta-tag:c++]  to be added, can you provide more context about this problem/question? Are you afraid the `scan_time` will be too high because of this addition of 2 ? In what context do you expect an answer, because this current piece of code has the `TODO: This will be further improved ....`, I do not see any harm in adding a random value of 2.

Comment: This is not a c++ question , as it is just a algorithm for the MySQL optimizer . If someone has MySQL optimizer background ,it would be easy to understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

A guess...

+1 could be justified for the following example:  A scan starting in the middle of one block and ending in the middle of the next block needs to fetch 2 blocks, while touching only 1 block's worth of rows.

The other +1 I would chalk up to general overhead (locating and opening the table).